# Samsung galaxy s6 dous no lte/4g option

Tags: samsung-mobile

I just bought a s6 dous and what I found is this that there no option for lte/4g after updating to android m. Someone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

It allows both Sim slot to use 3G/4G, but only one at a time. I am using it now.

Hania Mehak | [Oppo Mobile](http://www.mobile-phone.pk/oppo-mobiles/)

Comment: Hania mehak its not evening showing the 4g option in my phone. Thats the problem